# $(document).ready can't replace js declared at bottom of the page, but I need to have the script at the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready

I have JQuery based tab navigation that only works if it is placed after the html for the menu. It works if it's placed at the end too, but breaks when I put the same script in $(document).ready ath the top.

I thought that this (placed at the top of the page):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    mouseovertabsmenu.init("mytabsmenu", "mysubmenuarea", true);
});
</script>
```

would be the same as this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        mouseovertabsmenu.init("mytabsmenu", "mysubmenuarea", true);
    </script>
</html>
```

Which is placed at the bottom of the page and works. How would I be able to put the function at the top or even include it from a separate file?

Comment: If you put that `script` block *before* your `jQuery` include `script` block... You'll be calling something that's not available yet. Also, in the global scope, you should default to `jQuery()` instead of `$()`. But my guess is you're trying to use jQuery before it's been included (and the browser has access to `$` or `jQuery`).

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and I had used this in the head after the jquery include link:

```
$(document).ready(myfunction());
```

This failed due to objects not being loaded. I should have wrapped my call in a function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    myfunction();
});
```

This worked as expected only after the document was properly loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is recommended to place the script at the end of the page , is so that the HTML elements are loaded onto the page before you try to access them..

No matter where you place the code it is better to wrap in DOM ready event which makes sure the complete HTML document is properly loaded before you try to access the elements in the page..

Maybe in your case

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        mouseovertabsmenu.init("mytabsmenu", "mysubmenuarea", true);
    </script>
```

seems to be working when not encased in DOM ready is the function is not accessible as it's scope is being blocked by DOM ready

Comment: $(document).ready(...) is called only after all HTML is loaded and that is why it could be placed anywhere in page

Comment: Wrapping every block of Javascript in a `jQuery.ready()` block during page load is not, IMO, an acceptable practice.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I don't think they are saying to wrap every block of Javascript, but it's definitely a good practice to wrap DOM-related code in it...like event bindings or manipulations that require something in the DOM to be available.

Comment: @ianpgall - No, if the code is located following the elements it references, you do not need to `$.ready()` block that code unless there's some other consideration. It's simply not necessary in many situations (`$(window).load() would be preferable in certain circumstances as well`), and defaulting to just doing it is a poor habit to get into since it replaces understanding it in practice with a "might as well" coding practice. I would suggest considering wrapping all code in self initializers, though, like `(function load(){...})();` to remain out of the global scope.